# How can I generate documentation for a Python property setter using Sphinx?

Tags: python, properties, python-sphinx

I have a Python class something like the following, with docstrings intended to be converted into documentation by [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/):

```
class Direction(object):
    """
    A direction in which movement can be made.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = None

    @property
    def name(self):
        """
        The unique name of the direction.

        :return: The direction name
        :rtype: string
        """
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        """
        Sets the direction name.

        :param string value: The direction name
        """
        self._name = value
```

The Sphinx output looks something like this:

> *class* **Direction**(name)
>   A direction in which movement can be made.
>
> > **name**
> >     The unique name of the direction.
> >
> > > **Returns:** The direction name
> > >
> > > **Return type:** string

which is fine as far as it goes, but note the complete absence of any information about the `name` setter.

Is there any way to get Sphinx to generate documentation for the property setter?

Comment: It seems like it'd make more sense to document any special get/set behavior in the getter documentation if that's where Sphinx looks for it.  Your documentation for the setter here is basically superfluous: it's a property, so it obviously sets the value, and documenting the parameter is also needless because every setter requires the same argument, and the setter won't actually be called explicitly.  Special get/set behavior is really a characteristic of the property as a whole.  The point of properties is they're accessed via a single attribute name, not separate get/set function calls.

Comment: @BrenBarn I can certainly do that if that's what Sphinx is expecting. However, the generated documentation doesn't actually indicate that it's a property and I'm not sure how I can use the `:param:`, `:return:` and `:rtype:` tags to make this clear?

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch, Sphinx documents the getter without using `()`. This, along with your combined docstring, should help the user understand that it's a property.

Comment: @A-B-B Ah, I hadn't realized that. Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sphinx ignores docstrings on property setters so all documentation for a property must be on the `@property` method.

Whilst Sphinx understands certain specific tags (e.g. `:param ...:`) it will accept any custom tags and will render them as labels for the text which follows them.

Therefore something like the following will render the documentation in a reasonable way (`getter`, `setter` and `type` can be changed to any other text if required).

```
@property
def name(self):
    """
    The unique name of the direction.

    :getter: Returns this direction's name
    :setter: Sets this direction's name
    :type: string
    """
    return self._name
```

The generated documentation looks something like this:

> *class* **Direction**(name)
>   A direction in which movement can be made.
>
> > **name**
> >     The unique name of the direction.
> >
> > > **Getter:** Returns this direction's name
> > >
> > > **Setter:** Sets this direction's name
> > >
> > > **Type:** string

Thanks to @BrenBarm and @A-B-B for pointing me in the direction of this solution.